# Can I not use < in perl system() or am I missing something

Tags: mysql, perl

So writing a relatively simple script that rips through some log files, extracts some entries and generates a sql script to insert these entires into a database. 
All good so far, tested the extract file, and it looks like it generates OK, and I can open it up in sql Workbench and execute it without issues, I can also use the file with mysql from the command line. However, when I try to use system in the end of the perl script, it seems like it is skipping the redirect, i.e. mysql starts, and logs in to the database, but it does not read the sql file.

So here is the end of the perl script

```
print "mysql --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpassword $database < $wdir/$foname";
system( "$mysql", "--user=$dbuser --password=$dbpassword $database < $wdir/$foname" );
if ( $? == -1 ) {
    print "\ncommand failed: $!\n";
    exit 2;
} else {
    $exend = time();
    $exend = $exend - $extime;
    printf "SQL Load: $exend s\n";
}
```

And output from the script

```
> 1 file(s) will be translated to sql for DBFScalls
test.txt  test.sql  No Records: 50 mysql --user=###### --password=##### #### < /Users/ben/avaydev/test.sqlWelcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 229
Server version: 5.6.19 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try to pass `"mysql --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpassword $database < $wdir/$foname"` to the sytem sub

Comment: $mysql contains the full path to mysql, so $mysql="/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql";

Comment: MiguelP Prz: Thank you, that seems to have resolved the issue, when I passed the whole argument as one it worked, when it was split it missed the < for whatever reason. So the solution was system("$mysql --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpassword $database < $wdir/$foname");

Comment: Perhaps you should look into using the [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use more than one arg to `system` it passes the list straight to exec() without using the shell

Alter your line to

```
   system("$mysql --user=$dbuser --password=$dbpassword $database < $wdir/$foname");
```

So there is only one string passed and it should hit the shell and use the `<` correctly

dooh: as Miguel Prz said in the comments.  I should read the comments

Comment: Yes, but you also explained why :-)

Comment: Please note that passing a single argument to `system` will cause the string to be interpreted by whatever shell you're using. Since variables are interpolated into this string, this opens up the possibility of Shell injection.